# In Java Web application,how to Reflect a pie chart on the basis of database value?

Tags: java

In my java web application, i want to reflect pie chart dynamically on the basis of database value and give me a some way on the basis of that i can do it?? which is a better way do it either through STRUTS 2.0 or JSP,SERVLET. Thanks in advance.......

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10908696/how-can-i-display-pie-chart-in-jsp-page

Answer (score 1):

You need something that generates charts like [JFreeChart](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/) (on the server) or [Flot](http://www.flotcharts.org/) (in the browser).

It doesn't really make sense to ask if you should use 'Struts 2 or JSP,Servlet' - this is not really relevant to how you generate a chart - use whatever server side technology you think is appropriate.

Comment: Yes, that's certainly another option.

Comment: http://www.humblesoftware.com/flotr2/ - these charts look more modern, than the Flot ones.

Comment: actully sir my requirement is that pie chart should reflect from database value, is that google chart api concept will work in application????Thanks a lot....for your rply

Comment: Yes, if you're generating charts in the browser (google chart, flot, flotr2) then what you do is read the values from the database in your controller method (servlet or action etc.) and output these on a JSP in the format appropriate for the chart api that you're using.