# Unable to implement ModelDriven or ServletRequestAware in Struts 2 Action Class using JFree

Tags: struts2, jfreechart

I am trying to generate a chart based on user input.  I am using JFree Charts in a Struts 2 framework.  In the chart-generation Action class, I am unable to implement the `ModelDriven` concept; I am also unable to retrieve the parameter values from the `HttpServletRequest` Object. .

If I call the chart-generation action class with implementing `ModelDriven` or `ServletRequestAware`, it works fine but, it displays the chart on the next page.  I need to generate the chart based on user input.

I was unsuccessful searching for information on JFree an Struts 2; any useful tutorial links would also be appreciated.

this is my struts.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
"-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
"http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd ">
<struts>
<package name="jfree" extends="jfreechart-default">
            <action name="chartAction" class="com.kogent.action.ChartAction">
                <result name="success" type="chart">
                    <param name="width">500</param>
                    <param name="height">300</param> 
                </result>
            </action>
    </package>          
</struts>
```

and this is my Action class

```java
package com.kogent.action;

import java.util.Random;

import org.jfree.chart.JFreeChart;
import org.jfree.chart.axis.NumberAxis;
import org.jfree.chart.axis.ValueAxis;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.XYPlot;
import org.jfree.chart.renderer.xy.StandardXYItemRenderer;

import org.jfree.data.xy.XYSeries;
import org.jfree.data.xy.XYSeriesCollection;

import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ModelDriven;
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.Preparable;

public class ChartAction extends ActionSupport implements ModelDriven<FormBean>,Preparable{

    private JFreeChart chart;
    private FormBean bean;

    @Override
    public FormBean getModel() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return bean;
    }
    @Override
    public void prepare() throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        bean=new FormBean();
    }



    public String execute() throws Exception {
        // chart creation logic...
        System.out.print(bean.getCategory()+"    "+bean.getChartType());
        //if remove this above line my action runs fine but i require this vales from the user
        XYSeries dataSeries = new XYSeries(new Integer(1)); 
        for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i++) {

            dataSeries.add(i, new Random().nextInt(50));
        }

        XYSeriesCollection xyDataSet = new XYSeriesCollection(dataSeries);

        ValueAxis xAxis = new NumberAxis("Marks");
        ValueAxis yAxis = new NumberAxis("Age");
        chart =
            new JFreeChart("Chart Title", JFreeChart.DEFAULT_TITLE_FONT,
                new XYPlot(xyDataSet,xAxis, yAxis,
                        new StandardXYItemRenderer(StandardXYItemRenderer.LINES)),
                false);
        chart.setBackgroundPaint(java.awt.Color.white);

        return super.SUCCESS;
    }

    public JFreeChart getChart() {
        return chart;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post any relevant code for your Action, including your XML.

Comment: in my Action class am just implementing the ModelDriven and in struts.xml file, package tag extends jfreechart-default

Comment: @JoshDM can u hav a look i hav postd d cods

Answer (score 1):

Based on this jfree chart so many examples are there, 
just i am giving those links check it out.

`First`:Implementing any jfree chart there is nothing required other than `servlet request aware` and `servlet response aware`, request is for taking request from user and response is for giving output to the user that's it. It's your wish to use `'ModelDriven' interface ( it gains the extra ability to transfer the form data into the object automatically)`.

just use this links.

[Create chart and Display them dynamically in JSP](http://jspimageupload.blogspot.in/).

[Create area chart in JSP page using JFreeChart](http://www.roseindia.net/chartgraphs/areachart-jsppage.shtml).

[Creating Pie Charts with JFreeChart](http://www.vogella.com/articles/JFreeChart/article.html)

[Already discussion are there in stack overflow only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10908696/how-can-i-display-pie-chart-in-jsp-page)

[This is official site it will help full for you](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.1.x/docs/jfreechart-plugin.html)

Comment: creating chart and displaying them is not a problem buddy all in need is that get the value from the user through some form and the retrieve them in my action class which follows struts2 mvc framework which none of your example showed of followed .

Comment: K.use this link [jfree chart](http://www.ehow.com/how_12002125_create-pie-chart-jsp-using-jfreechart.html).Here you have to modify ,implement servlet requestaware in action class and replace with this code. eg: `data.setValue("One", new Double(43.2));` here instead of **double** put `request.getParameter("your string");` it will looks like  `data.setValue("One",request.getParameter("your string"))` it will work 100%